# Using the same framework in Watchkit extension and app generates warning

Tags: ios, xcode

I've created a framework, and Im noticing that if I use the same framework within the watchkit and the main app, I recieve the following error messages.

`objc[86669]: Class BasicHTTPServer_ObjC is implemented in both /Users/currentUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProj-egxerbveipszypdazxgpuyifbwcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DataKit.framework/DataKit and /Users/currentUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0661376-772D-4B5A-8427-0EF7A55326F2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/05F0BD13-2736-4180-89E5-39CF64167218/myApp.app/PlugIns/MyApp WatchKit Extension.appex/nyApp WatchKit Extension. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

This error is repeated also for other classes SocketServer_Objc, SSDPDB_ObjC, SSDPDBDevice_ObjC, MediaServer1ItemRes, TelephonyServer1Device, TelephonyClient1Device, SoapActionsMessaging1, SoapActionsMediaManagement1.

Currently, there is only a warning, and by looking at these kind of error messages I have encountered situations in which crashes occur over these kind of issues.